# How do i export tfs 2010 comments into a changelog file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs, tfsbuild

I want to export TFS2010 comments from a date range or continually, (which ever works) into a changelog.txt file or similar.

I have looked all over the web trying to find examples or documentation on how to do this, but cannot find anything.
Also microsoft's website seems to just redirect me to TFS2012.

Comment: I wondered if there where any programs that do this already.

We were thinking if we should just copy out comments into a changelog file, or if something or someway exists to copy these automatically either at build time or on each commit.

Comment: I know this is possible in svn, using the commit scripts, but i dont know if tfs can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to output the "History" between a date range, but this will get you a lot more than the comments.

```
tf history "$/Project/Main" /format:detailed /noprompt /recursive /v:D"13 Jun 2013 00:00"~D"01 Jun 2013 00:00"
```

You could use the Brief format, but this is limited in it's width, and will truncate longer comments.

Once you have your "Log" you will have to parse it yourself. TFS does not have a format like git does.

You could create a console App that reads the history from `Console.In.ReadToEnd()` and then parses it into just comments and just pipe the results of your `tf history` into it.

You could also query the TFS API for this information using the [VersionControlServer.QueryHistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.queryhistory%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method, and just get the comments and output those.